# Drools Workbench 6.5 with JBOSS EAP 7.0.3

Tags: jboss7.x, drools

I have a local setup of JBOSS EAP 7.0 version installed and running.
When trying to deploy the Drools Workbench 6.5 EAP7.x WAR file, it fails with the following exceptions.

```
12:58:25,726 WARN  [org.jbpm.executor.impl.ExecutorImpl] (MSC service thread 1-8) Disabling JMS support in executor because: unable to initialize JMS configurat
ion for executor due to JmsXA -- service jboss.naming.context.java.JmsXA
12:58:27,144 ERROR [org.uberfire.java.nio.file.api.FileSystemProviders] (MSC service thread 1-8) Can't initialize FileSystemProviders: java.util.ServiceConfigur
ationError: org.uberfire.java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider: Provider org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider could not be instantiated
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.api.FileSystemProviders.buildProviders(FileSystemProviders.java:65)
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.api.FileSystemProviders.setup(FileSystemProviders.java:48)
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.api.FileSystemProviders.resolveProvider(FileSystemProviders.java:104)
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:117)
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:83)
        at org.uberfire.io.impl.AbstractIOService.newFileSystem(AbstractIOService.java:244)
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer$2.create(SystemConfigProducer.java:274)
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer$2.create(SystemConfigProducer.java:209)
        at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:99)
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystem$1366014920$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getPath(Unknown Source)
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserServicesExtendedBackEndImpl.buildPath(SocialUserServicesExtendedBackEndImpl.java:51)
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.persistence.SocialUserCachePersistence.<init>(SocialUserCachePersistence.java:57)
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.persistence.SocialUserInstancePersistence.<init>(SocialUserInstancePersistence.java:31)
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer.setupSocialUserPersistenceAPI(SocialUserPersistenceProducer.java:93)
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer.setup(SocialUserPersistenceProducer.java:87)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:98)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:81)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:126)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:171)
        at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$ApplicationScopedContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:141)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(Unknown Source)
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.runPostConstruct(SystemConfigProducer.java:162)
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.afterDeploymentValidation(SystemConfigProducer.java:143)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:309)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:124)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:287)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:265)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:271)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:260)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:148)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:35)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:449)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:96)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.uberfire.java.nio.IOException: java.io.IOException: Failed to open server socket for /127.0.0.1:9418
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider.buildAndStartDaemon(JGitFileSystemProvider.java:613)
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider.<init>(JGitFileSystemProvider.java:463)
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider.<init>(JGitFileSystemProvider.java:395)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
        ... 63 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to open server socket for /127.0.0.1:9418
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.daemon.git.Daemon.start(Daemon.java:213)
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider.buildAndStartDaemon(JGitFileSystemProvider.java:611)
        ... 71 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
        at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.java:137)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
        at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.bind(TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.java:110)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.daemon.git.Daemon.start(Daemon.java:211)
        ... 72 more

12:58:27,207 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-eap
7.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-eap7.war".WeldStartService: Failed to
start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer.setup
() on org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer@4eb699d7
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:100)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:81)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:126)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:171)
        at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$ApplicationScopedContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:141)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(Unknown Source)
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.runPostConstruct(SystemConfigProducer.java:162)
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.afterDeploymentValidation(SystemConfigProducer.java:143)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:309)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:124)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:287)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:265)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:271)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:260)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:148)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:35)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:449)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:96)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:98)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.api.FileSystemProviders.getProvider(FileSystemProviders.java:114)
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.api.FileSystemProviders.resolveProvider(FileSystemProviders.java:107)
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:117)
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:83)
        at org.uberfire.io.impl.AbstractIOService.newFileSystem(AbstractIOService.java:244)
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer$2.create(SystemConfigProducer.java:274)
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer$2.create(SystemConfigProducer.java:209)
        at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:99)
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystem$1366014920$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getPath(Unknown Source)
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserServicesExtendedBackEndImpl.buildPath(SocialUserServicesExtendedBackEndImpl.java:51)
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.persistence.SocialUserCachePersistence.<init>(SocialUserCachePersistence.java:57)
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.persistence.SocialUserInstancePersistence.<init>(SocialUserInstancePersistence.java:31)
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer.setupSocialUserPersistenceAPI(SocialUserPersistenceProducer.java:93)
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer.setup(SocialUserPersistenceProducer.java:87)
        ... 42 more

        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:37)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:449)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:96)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        ... 3 more

12:58:27,304 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deploym
ent" => "kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-eap7.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-ea
p7.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-eap7.war\".WeldStartService: Fa
iled to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer.setup
() on org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer@4eb699d7
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:100)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:81)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:126)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:171)
        at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$ApplicationScopedContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:141)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(Unknown Source)
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.runPostConstruct(SystemConfigProducer.java:162)
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.afterDeploymentValidation(SystemConfigProducer.java:143)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:309)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:124)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:287)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:265)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:271)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:260)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:148)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:35)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:449)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:96)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:98)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.api.FileSystemProviders.getProvider(FileSystemProviders.java:114)
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.api.FileSystemProviders.resolveProvider(FileSystemProviders.java:107)
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:117)
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:83)
        at org.uberfire.io.impl.AbstractIOService.newFileSystem(AbstractIOService.java:244)
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer$2.create(SystemConfigProducer.java:274)
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer$2.create(SystemConfigProducer.java:209)
        at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:99)
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystem$1366014920$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getPath(Unknown Source)
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserServicesExtendedBackEndImpl.buildPath(SocialUserServicesExtendedBackEndImpl.java:51)
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.persistence.SocialUserCachePersistence.<init>(SocialUserCachePersistence.java:57)
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.persistence.SocialUserInstancePersistence.<init>(SocialUserInstancePersistence.java:31)
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer.setupSocialUserPersistenceAPI(SocialUserPersistenceProducer.java:93)
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer.setup(SocialUserPersistenceProducer.java:87)
        ... 42 more
"}}
12:58:27,354 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-eap7.war" was rolled bac
k with the following failure message:
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-eap7.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in
service jboss.deployment.unit.\"kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-eap7.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer.setup
() on org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer@4eb699d7
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:100)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:81)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:126)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:171)
```

... more

Can someone please suggest what i am missing here?

Comment: It does look to me as a port conflict. `Address already in use: JVM_Bind` is generally raised when Java ask for a port which is already used by another program. I suppose the conflicting port is 9418. Google will get you the command you should run on windows or linux to discover which program is using which port. Either shut down this program or change the port of git daemon. Have a look at https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch18.html#wb.systemProperties.

Comment: It worked when i changed all the ports. However, since i was behind a FW, it was not able to install again. It failed with this:  "xception: https://github.com/guvnorngtestuser1/guvnorng-playground.git: cannot open git-upload-pack"

Comment: Is there a way to bypass it? my org doesnt allow download from git

Comment: Another issue. I was able to bypass the git issue using the property -Dorg.kie.demo=false.

Comment: Another issue. I was able to bypass the git issue using the property -Dorg.kie.demo=false.

Now post that when i again try to deploy, it throws the following error:

`2017-03-21 16:56:18,119 WARN  [org.jbpm.executor.impl.ExecutorRunnable] (pool-11-thread-1) Error while executing jobs due to null
2017-03-21 16:56:18,851 ERROR [org.kie.api.builder.KieScanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) Unable to create MavenProject from InputStream: org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedderException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for junit:junit:jar:4.12`

Please suggest

Comment: More:

`
`2017-03-21 16:56:21,096 ERROR [org.kie.api.builder.KieScanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) Unable to create MavenProject from InputStream: org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedderException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for junit:junit:jar:4.12`

Comment: `KieScanner` tries to download all the transitive dependencies of your Maven projects. Did you configure a custom `settings.xml` Maven file and loaded it with the `kie.maven.settings.custom` configuration property ? In it you can define URL's of Maven repositories with credentials. I guess your org does not allow call to Maven central due to FW and/or proxies. Try to google for custom Maven settings in the context of workbench, you should find a bit of material.

Comment: You are right! The FW policies dont allow us to go outside for pulling Maven. However, on the JBOSS Server, i setup 2 properties, http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort, bunced the server, yet it gave me the same error. 
Do i need to give this proxy setting during project build only?

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot answer to this question, I do not know proxy configuration for workbench. You may have better opening a new question as this is unrelated to the original question.

Comment: my bad. thats respoved. i had to set the following properties on JBOSS console https.proxyHost and https.proxyPort. Once done it was able to move forward.

Comment: However, now facing a new issue.

`org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void org.kie.workbench.drools.backend.server.LuceneConfigProducer.setup() on org.kie.workbench.drools.backend.server.LuceneConfigProducer@2f8ed0da`
Followed by 
`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/opt/app/jboss/jboss-eap-7.0/.index/datasets/write.lock`

Any suggestions?

Comment: are there any dependencies that i need to make sure are available for Workbench? This is going more into a research mode, i resolve one issue, facing another and keeps n going in cycles.
If you or anyone can point me in the direction of any pre-requisites, that would really help!